# Error: Internal Server Error (500) How to resolve this issue?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I will install theme and plugins successfully. When i will click on import demo data button after activate plugins, i get an error. **Error: Internal Server Error (500)** How to resolve this issue?

Note: I have LAMP Centos 7 Linux Server with 1GB RAM, 25GB Storage

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to help in troubleshooting **Internal Server Error (500)** error:

1. First of all, Go **FTP** into your website
2. Open the file named `wp-config.php` on the root.
3. Find the line where you see `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`
4. Change `false` to `true` and save the file

And now you refresh the page you were getting an error on you should now see more descriptive error messages which will help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in your /wp-admin/ folder and name it php.ini
Add these to the file :

```
memory_limit = 256M
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 
max_execution_time = 180
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Save it. This worked for me :)